# Writing an assembler , need help

Tags: compiler-construction, x86, assembly

I'm writing an 8086 assembler for a college project . I've gone through some material on compiler design on the internet and am reading the 'dragon book' of compilers . But the problem is I couldn't find much about the assembling (generating object code) part here . Are there any good books or links for assembler design . Where do I start ?, I've gone through lexical analysis,parsing and intermediate code generation .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you just punt and generate a .COM file?  It is loaded into a code segment at :0100 and executed with CS, DS, ES, and SS all pointed to that segment.

If you could do that, then generating code gets a LOT easier.

Your test program would be simple

```
mov dx, 110
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ax,4c00
int 21

at address 110:
"Hello, World!" 0d 0a 24
```

Comment: Hmm. Memories from the past just passed by in my mind while reading your code. It has been a long time...

Comment: @Yves: Same here, written the same program in 80886, z80, 6301, 6502 and 1802 over the years, but none in the last decade.

Comment: great answer, but you should perhaps point out that the above example requires either MS-DOS or an MS-DOS shell under Windows.  God only knows where int 21 would take you in other OS's

Comment: Right, as MacLaughlin implies, you cannot use interrupts in real mode Windows, meaning that the code above will not work in any OS after Windows 98.

Comment: LOL! The days of programs that are 5 instructions, long gone.

Comment: @doug65536: Yeah, it's 6 or maybe even 7 instructions now.  Push, push, push, push, `call MessageBoxA`, `ret`.  (Iczelion's tuts recommend `push 0`, `call ExitProcess` rather than `ret`.)  The horror!

Answer (score 3):

The dragon book is totally the wrong source because an assembler is not a compiler. The "grammer" of an assembler line is extremly simple (regular grammer - not context sensitive).

The code generation part for an assembler is almost non existing. Get a good reference book about the opcodes of your target CPU and just generate the bytes as explained.

There a few nice simple assemblers out there and you should look at them. Learning by code reading is a very effective way for a college project. You will need it because the Intel Assembler code is extremely ugly at least if you want target some of the extensions as well.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/pharabee/344751/344751/how-to-write-a-assembler/

Answer (score 1):

You need a mapping between mnemonic instructions like MOV and opcodes see [OpcodeMap](http://www.mlsite.net/8086/#tbl_map1). Besides that you need the information how many arguments (and width of operators) a instruction requires (encoded in bit fields, that will save you much time if you get this right).

I doubt that the dragon book will help you much.

[The Art of
ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE
PROGRAMMING](http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/toc.html) is a good reference.

Comment: The link seems broken. Is this the same one: http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/artofasm.html

Answer (score 0):

try to use llvm compiler infrastructure.

http://llvm.org/ProjectsWithLLVM/

Comment: Believe it or not, I have a similar area I'm working -- it's for an education effort, and the students will write assembly directly, so I need an assembler and linker/loader for the virtual CPU.  In practice, assembly is just a lot of string processing -- I didn't need ANTLR etc.  It's just read a line, tokenize it, and parse the line.  Since assembly doesn't usually have multiline statements, that's about it.  Linker loaders are a bit more complex!